# Can not create regex. Suppose it should be simple

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I will try to explain it with the following example:

```
' text::'
'text::'
```

This pattern:

```
(?<=^).+(?=::)
```

matches ' text' in the first line, and 'text' in the second. I need a pattern, that matches 'text' (without leading space) in both lines.

Comment: If you have specific requirements:`Java`, **it should have been added from the beginning in your original post**. You waste my time I spent to make you a complete solution. Very low post quality. Please take a look at [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

I edited for you this time.

Comment: Sorry for your time wasting, but I haven`t got much experience in regex (otherwise I would know how to solve this case), and this is the reason why I have not point my platform in my post. But now I think someone with much experience SHOULD KNOW that platform matters before waste his time for giving an answer that is not acceptable for "all possible cases" (\K).
But thank you very much in any case, I have learned a new feature that some day can be on place.
By the way, I have edited my post adding java-platform, and dont see it.

Comment: It's not about regex experience, but about giving the right informations in your post from the beginning

Comment: I am sorry once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### This regex:

```
[^\s':]+(?=:)
```

##### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r9iOWz/1)

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `[^\s':]+` | any character except: whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " "), ''', ':' (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `(?=` | [look ahead](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) to see if there is: |
| `:` | : |
| `)` | end of look-ahead |

Comment: Thank you! I need a pattern supported by jave. I schould point it in the question, sorry. I'll try to edit if possible.

Comment: Yes, your pattern works.
It canches not only the 1st match, for example here
' match::some::text::
there are three matches, but for me it doesn't matter. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

thaThis pattern:

```
(?:^.{1})(?: )?(.+?(?=::))
```

looks more complex than in the answer above, but in this text:

```
' match::some::text::
```

gives only one match.